# Is there a R markdown analog of \SweaveInput{} for modular report generation?

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc, sweave, r-markdown

One of the features I like very much in Sweave is the option to have \SweaveInput{} of separate Sweave files to have a more "modular" report and just be able to comment out parts of the report that I do not want to be generated with a single `#\SweaveInput{part_x}` rather than having to comment in or out entire blocks of code. 
Recently I decided to move to R Markdown for multiple reasons being mainly practicality, the option of interactive (Shiny) integration in the report and the fact that I do not really need the extensive formatting options of LaTeX. 
I found that technically pandoc is able to combine multiple Rmd files into one html output by just concatenating them but it would be nice if this behaviour could be called from a "master" Rmd file.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated even if it is just "go back to Sweave, it is not possible in Markdown".

I am using R 3.1.1 for Windows and Linux as well as Rstudio 0.98.1056 and Rstudio server 0.98.983.

Comment: I would put this as an answer but I don't use \SweaveInput so I'm not sure if this answers it.  But this link looks useful: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dieter's answer below shows that this is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like this in the main document:

````
```{r child="CapsuleRInit.Rmd"}
```
```{r child="CapsuleTitle.Rmd", eval=TRUE}
```
```{r child="CapsuleBaseline.Rmd", eval=TRUE}
```
````

Use `eval=FALSE` to skip one child.

For RStudio users: you can define a main document for latex output, but this does not work for RMD documents, so you always have to switch to the main document for processing. Please support my feature request to RStudio; I tried already twice, but is seems to me that too few people use child docs to put it higher in the priority list.

Comment: How can I support your feature request?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to submit the feature request [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues)?

Comment: I have already submitted one, and supported another request of somebody else. It's not a knitr feature, therefore the link Dason gave is not the right place, but rather one of RSTudio.

Comment: @FM Kerckhof: See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200657197-Root-document-for-Knit-HTML?locale=en-us if you and others would like to second the feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand some of the terms in the answer above, but the solution relates to defining a custom knit: hook in the YAML header. For multipartite documents this allows you to, for example:

- Have a 'main' or 'root' Rmarkdown file with an `output: markdown_document` YAML header
- render all child documents from Rmd ⇒ md ahead of calling `render`, or not if this is time-limiting
- combine multiple files (with the child code chunk option) into one (e.g. for chapters in a report)
- write `output: html_document` (or other format) YAML headers for this compilation output on the fly, prepending to the markdown effectively writing a fresh Rmarkdown file

  - ...then render this Rmarkdown to get the output, deleting intermediate files in the process if desired

[image]

The code for all of the above ([dumped here](https://gist.github.com/lmmx/c78fc428720146c2f939)) is described [here](http://biochemistri.es/modular-workbook), a post I wrote after working out the usage of custom `knit:` YAML header hooks recently ([here](http://biochemistri.es/one-weird-rmd-trick)).

The custom `knit:` function (i.e. the replacement to `rmarkdown::render`) in the above example is:

```
(function(inputFile, encoding) {
  input.dir <- normalizePath(dirname(inputFile))
  rmarkdown::render(input = inputFile, encoding = encoding, quiet=TRUE,
                    output_file = paste0(input.dir,'/Workbook-tmp.Rmd'))
  sink("Workbook-compiled.Rmd")
    cat(readLines(headerConn <- file("Workbook-header.yaml")), sep="\n")
    close(headerConn)
    cat(readLines(rmdConn <- file("Workbook-tmp.Rmd")), sep="\n")
    close(rmdConn)
  sink()

  rmarkdown::render(input = paste0(input.dir,'/Workbook-compiled.Rmd'),
                  encoding = encoding, output_file = paste0(input.dir,'/../Workbook.html'))
  unlink(paste0(input.dir,'/Workbook-tmp.Rmd'))
})
```

...but all squeezed onto 1 line!

The rest of the 'master'/'root'/'control' file or whatever you want to call it takes care of writing the aforementioned YAML for the final HTML output that goes via an intermediate Rmarkdown file, and its second code chunk programmatically appends child documents through a call to `list.files()`

````
```{r include=FALSE}
header.input.file <- "Workbook-header.yaml"
header.input.dir <- normalizePath(dirname(header.input.file))
fileConn <- file(header.input.file)
writeLines(c(
  "---",
  paste0('title: "', rmarkdown::metadata$title,'"'),
  "output:",
  "  html_document:",
  "    toc: true",
  "    toc_depth: 3 # defaults to 3 anyway, but just for ease of modification",
  "    number_sections: TRUE",
  paste0("    css: ",paste0(header.input.dir,'/../resources/workbook_style.css')),
  '    pandoc_args: ["--number-offset=1", "--atx-headers"]',
  "---", sep="\n"),
  fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

```{r child = list.files(pattern = 'Notes-.*?\\.md')}
# Use file names with strict numeric ordering, e.g. Notes-001-Feb1.md
```
````

The directory structure would contain a top-level folder with

1. A final output `Workbook.html`
2. A `resources` subfolder containing `workbook_style.css`
3. A `documents` subfolder containing said main file "Workbook.Rmd" alongside files named as "Notes-001.Rmd", "Notes-002.Rmd" etc. (to ensure a fileglobbing on `list.files(pattern = "Notes-.*?\\.Rmd)` finds and thus makes them children in the correct order when rendering the main `Workbook.Rmd` file)

[image]
[image]

To get proper numbering of files, each constituent "Notes-XXX.Rmd" file should contain the following style YAML header:

````
---
title: "March: Doing x, y, and z"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { input.dir <- normalizePath(dirname(inputFile)); rmarkdown::render(input = inputFile, encoding = encoding, quiet=TRUE)})
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
    pandoc_args: "--atx-headers"
---

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis', comment=''}
cat("##", rmarkdown::metadata$title)
```
````

The code chunk at the top of the Rmarkdown document enters the YAML title as a second-level header when evaluated. `results='asis'` indicates to return plain text-string rather than

```
[1] "A text string"
```

You would knit each of these *before* knitting the main file - it's easier to remove the requirement to render all child documents and just append their pre-produced markdown output.

I've described all of this at the links above, but I thought it'd be bad manners not to leave the actual code with my answer.

I don't know how effective that RStudio feature request website may be... Personally I've not found it hard to look into the source code for these functions, which thankfully are [open source](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown), and if there really is something *absent* rather than undocumented an inner-workings-informed feature request is likely far more actionable by one of their software devs.

I'm not familiar with Sweave, was the above was what you were aiming at? If I understand correctly you just want to control the inclusion of documents in a modular fashion. The `child = list.files()` statement could take care of that: if not through file globbing you can straight-up list files as `child = c("file1.md","file2md")`... and switch that statement to change the children. You can also control TRUE/FALSE switches with YAML, whereby the presence of a custom header would set some children to be included for example

```
potentially.absent.variable: TRUE
```

...above the document with a silent `include=FALSE` hiding the machinations of the first chunk:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
!all(!as.logical(rmarkdown::metadata$potentially.absent.variable)
# ==> FALSE if potentially.absent.variable is absent
# ==> FALSE if anything other than TRUE
# ==> TRUE if TRUE

checkFor <- function(var) {
  return !all(!as.logical(rmarkdown::metadata[[var]])
}
```

```{r child = "Optional_file.md", eval = checkFor(potentially.absent.variable)}
```
````